# Having a subscript out of range error 9 on this ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Generic Sheet).OLEDBConnection

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having a subscript out of range error 9 on this line of code

`With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Generic Sheet").OLEDBConnection`

Anyone know of some possible reasons other than not having the sheet in my workbook or it being misspelled? Both of those things are fine. Also it is the only workbook open on my computer.

Comment: You are using `ActiveWorkbook.Connections`. You need to provide a connection name, not a sheet name.

Comment: I got it thank you man